Why not use "their jobs" but use "their job" instead in "Some workers say they have been thinking about how to start over if their job gets cut. "?
From Boeing sending layoff notices to about 10% of its workforce 0:15

Boeing's CEO said it was trimming away 10% of their workforce after
they experienced $25 billion in losses in the last five years. Some
workers say they have been thinking about how to start over if their
job gets cut.

In the previous text, it was always "their jobs", so why is it "their job" here?

Possible dup of Using a plural possessive pronoun for a singular noun? See "Those who qualify will be awarded a certificate" or "those who qualify will be awarded certificates"? and "Everybody's using a cell phone nowadays" vs. "Everybody's using cell phones nowadays" as asked on ELU. In your example, initial they is definitely plural, but I'd say their is an example of "singular they", since each worker only has one job.

Note that it would also be perfectly valid and natural to have their jobs ("plural they") instead. It's really just a stylistic choice here, and although the switch from "plural" to "singular" may look odd to non-Anglophones, there's nothing particularly unusual about this usage to native Anglophones. Speaking as a Brit, I'd have probably made the stylistic choice to use "plural they" for the company anyway: Boeing's CEO said they were trimming away 10% of their workforce...

Using the singular "job" makes it clear that the workers are just thinking about what to do if their own job is cut, rather than thinking about all the other workers who will also be laid off.
This doesn't really need to be said explicitly. If they'd written "their jobs", most would assume that they only worry about themselves, as there's not much they can do about anyone else.
